# can't resolve host (A) but FQDN is fine

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, internal-dns

I am getting inconsistent name resolution locally with DNS

I have 3 2012 Standard servers and some weirdness on 1.

It is a standard install with IIS role added.

TEST01 is a dev server. 192.119.1.220 with a host header of TEST01.

DATA01 runs internal DNS on .240 and all servers and clients point here for DNS. There is a forward in DNS to 192.119.1.1 (router) with ISP external DNS #s mapped.

if I ping TEST01 from a non AD machine, it I get "Could not find Host TEST01"

If I ping TEST01 from a domain machine(another server), it resolves the IP but does not respond.

if I ping TEST01.AD.local, DNS resolves the IP, but times out.

I can access IIS by entering http://test.WWWDOMAIN.com and I can RDP to it, just not ping.

Any idea where I should start?

Answer (score 5):

You can't ping because Windows firewall is blocking ICMP. Allow ICMP if you'd like it to respond to pings.

Your non-domain joined computer can't reach it by the short name, because your domain-joined machines are automatically appending their suffix to queries. You can manually configure search suffixes in the network adapter's properties if you'd like.

All of this is working as expected.

Comment: When there's somethin' strange... in the neighborhood... who ya' gonna call... @MDMarra

Comment: Actually the non-joined computer can see and ping the other 2 servers  by the short name as well as the IP.

Comment: Then why did you say "if I ping TEST01 from a non AD machine, it I get "Could not find Host TEST01" ?

Comment: Because I can't, but APP01 and DATA01 work fine.

Comment: Well, I went back in after taking a break and its all responding normally again except for the sortname I created for TEST01 as "test". now I also have a shortname on DATA01 called "intranet" that works. I am wondering if there is another cache I need to clear other than flushing dns and restarting the DNS service.